# Row filtering based on user permissions in mysql

Tags: mysql, go, database-design, filtering

I'm currently designing a loan management system that is to be implemented in an island-wide company that has separate branches and a head office. Main users of this system are, recovery officers, branch managers, regional managers and head office staff. I need an approach in a such a way that when each of the users login to the system, they only see data relevant to them. For example, a recovery officer can only access loans related to them, branch managers can only see their branch loans and head office people can see all loans etc. Initially I came up with the following design.

```
loan
-------------------
id PK
capital
interest
......
recovery_officer_id FK
branch_id FK
region_id FK
```

Since each loan has relevant **recovery_officer_id**, **branch_id**, **region_id** columns to filter out data. I decided to create a table that has filters

```
filter
-----------
user_id FK
column_name
value
```

So in the code, I can append the relevant column names values to the **WHERE** clause to filter out results. For head office users, since there's no filter, I can ignore adding the **WHERE** clause.

But I feel like appending a variable length of **WHERE** clause every time is going to be a tedious task. Furthermore, if the query currently has a WHERE clause, I should write a generic code that appends the filter clause to it. So there must be a better approach to implement this. I'm using MySQL as my database and Go as my server side language. Any design ideas are highly appreciated.

Comment: It looks like you are on the right track.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Plan A  (preferred):  Build the checks into application code that interfaces between the user and the database.  That is, no one logs directly into the db.

I prefer to build WHERE clauses from scratch.  It gets tricky to edit an existing WHERE.  Think about the mess of ending with an OR clause, then tacking on an AND clause.  A savvy user could say

```
SELECT ... FROM ... WHERE 1 OR 2;
```

Then you tack on something like this:

```
SELECT ... FROM ... WHERE 1 OR 2 AND role = 'clerk';
```

Guess what -- the clerk gets to see everything.

Plan B:  Lots of VIEWs and column-level permissions to keep individuals from seeing things that shouldn't.